# JQuery: scrollTop() exactly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, scrolltop

Want to recognize if the user scrolls up or down with this snippet

```
        $('#songs-ul').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
            if(scrolling != 1){

                alert($("#songs-ul").scrollTop());
                if($("#songs-ul").scrollTop() > scrollheight){_runter();}

                if($("#songs-ul").scrollTop() < scrollheight){_rauf();}

                //scrollheight = $("#songs-ul").scrollTop();
            }
        });
```

But if the user scrolls "one time", it is no change - just at a second scroll it changes.

For a preview: http://www.limesoft-solutions.com/jukebox/index.php?list=1&yt=1
(it's the song list under the search field with "Suchen" text)

Has anybody a tip for it? :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to determine if the user is scrolling up or down:

```
(function () {
    var previousScroll = 0;
    $('#songs-ul').scroll(function () {
       var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
       if (currentScroll > previousScroll){
          alert('Im scrolling down');
          //add your code here
       }
       else {
          alert('Im scrollign up');
          //add your code here
       }
       previousScroll = currentScroll;
    });
}());
```

**[Here is an Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5rzzbunk/7/)**

Comment: Yeah, I use this I the functions. But .scrollTop() doesn't recognize every move.

If you open my link and go to the song list and scroll down - the popup window will tell you, that scrollTop is 0 - but you've scrolled.

Comment: If just every 2nd scroll will be recognized, then just every 2nd scroll will be transformed. And it doesn't look smooth ;)